# How to mark days of the week as Chiness in the PHP format function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$date_sw = new DateTime();

$date_swc = $date_sw->format('Y/n/j/(D)');
```

Is there a way to display the day of the week in Chinese characters?

The format document says that there is no way to display

the day of the week in Chinese characters.

How can I express the day of the week in Chinese?

Comment: Refer to [How to use Twig date to show week day in Chinese text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19263560/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array of weekdays in a Chinese character and get your weekdays

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');

// Get the parts of today's date
$now = getdate();
$y = $now['year'];
$m = $now['mon'];
$d = $now['mday'];
//$wday = $this->day_of_week($now['wday']);//for codeigniter
$wday = day_of_week($now['wday']);//for core php


printf("{$wday}");
function day_of_week($n) {
    $weekdays = array("星期日", "星期一", "星期二", "星期三", "星期四", "星期五", "星期六");
    return $weekdays[$n];
}
```

Maybe it helps you.

Comment: I tried to do what you asked but it did not work. And if you run it as you told it, then you can do it in format ()?

Comment: I solved this now. I'm so proud.    $week = array("日","月","火","水","木","金","土");

                                $s = $week[date("w")];

                                $date_sw = new DateTime($child['lasttrialtime']);
                                $date_swc = $date_sw->format('Y/n/j/H時:i分(').$s.").";